# How to change/resume a session?

Tags: php, symfony, session

I'm using Symfony 2.7 and try to resume a session which has been interrupted by closing the browser window and clearing cookies. Now I want to resume this session by visiting a page and entering the session ID of the old, interrupted session.

The naive approach doesn't work:

```
class TestController extends Controller {

    public function resumeSessionAction(Request $request) {
        $request->getSession()->setId('known old id');
        $this->redirectToRoute(...); //display route with the data from the old session
    }

}
```

leads to a LogicException

> Cannot change the ID of an active session

Is it generally possible to switch a session if you are working in another session?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried to manually set cookie `PHPSESSID` and redirect the user so symfony can load session with the value from `PHPSESSID` ?

Answer (score 1):

When user comes back to the site after closing the browser, the session most likely won't exist anymore.

However, you can implement a "remember me" functionality to keep user logged in, even if he closes the browser and comes back.

See the relevant chapter in the documentation on how to implement this: [How to Add "Remember Me" Login Functionality](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/remember_me.html).

Answer (score 0):

With your code, you're trying to get the current session and change its id, which - as your logic error points out - cannot be done.

Reading the doc for the [Session](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.html) and [Request](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html) classes, what you should do is to create a new Session object from the given ID and then set it as current session:

```
$session = new Session();
$session->setId($known old id);
$request->setSession($session)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I forgot to mention I tried this already and it leads to the same error. Unfortunately you can't replace the active session this way. Currently I'm using Vadims method of sending a `PHPSESSID` cookie with the old ID and reload the page.